# Expo - Icon doesn't show on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using `NativeBase` icon on my react app. But when i tried to run it on Android, all of my icons won't show up and i got this following error

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 11): Error: The method
>   or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on
>   android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies
>   properly?

Can someone help me? I've been stuck in this problem for days. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet as well what you have? Thanks!

Comment: The problem i don't even know which code cause this error, but when i run it on [expo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en) app on Android everything back normal

Comment: Are you calling FileSystem.loadAsync somewhere in your code? Are you sure it's related to NativeBase icons installation/usage? The error seems to point in another direction, maybe if you could provide us some code we could be more helpful. Does it work if you don't import/use the icons?

Comment: did you check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057816/8079868

Comment: I did, but it still happens

Comment: @HanifNr can you share reproducible github?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a version compatibility issue

install vector-icon by this command

```
expo install @expo/vector-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
expo install expo-file-system
```

If you are using icons from `react-native-vector-icons`, execute following command:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

if you are not using `react-native-vector-icons`, make following chnnages:

> import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; instead of.. import
>   Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';.

Once the above steps are done, Restart your app.
I hope it will solve your problem. [Refernce](https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/?redirected)

Comment: Still got the same warning, and i use `NativeBase`  icon instead of `vector-icons`

Comment: Did you try just `react-native link` and rerun the application? Also if possible, just type icon code you are using.